# LoginWindowUI.nib

Tags: xcode, button, ibaction

I'm new into this.. trying to create a simple app for macosx, basically I want this app to startup right after the user login with username/password..

and it's just a simple app has a window & that window displays a warning message and then have two buttons "agree" & "decline"
if the user hit agree then it will continue to the login process.. works as "LOG IN button"

if the user hit Decline then it will go back to the loginwindow..works like "CANCEL button"

but since am new into Xcode.. I have already created the app with both buttons.. but don't know how to add IBAction and Outlets!..

Any ideas?..

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

[This](http://cookingcocoa.blogspot.com/2009/01/iboutlet-ibaction-definition.html) should give you an idea. Also, since you are new to ios/mac dev, I would suggest you to read the [documents](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/navigation/#section=Resource%20Types&topic=Getting%20Started) from Apple that will provide you with a wealth of information. Additionally, read the [FAQ](https://stackoverflow.com/faq) of the site to get a better understanding how SO functions.